# Pyglet : Alternative to avoid slow FPS when writing text?

Tags: pyglet, pyopengl

I need to display text on my screen without dropping frames, at 120 Hz. The code is working fine until I put on some text (menu options), then it drops to 47 Hz. I know that the problem is the amount of text I am displaying. I thought about writing the text in texture and display it as a static image, but I don't know if it's possible. Is it? If so how?

I am very new to OpenGl, I started to read the RED book (7th edition), but I am still trying to understand how everything works. My code needs to be cross platform and can use only Pyopengl / pyglet. Any help/ advise would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.

```
def on_draw(dt):
    left = True
    right = False
    Rval = 0.0/255.0
    Gval = 153.0/255.0
    Bval = 0.0/255.0

    ShapePosition()

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    DrawChecker(Nbr = 16, Dark = 25.0/255, Light = 75.0/255)

    if ScreenSwap == 1:
        DrawQuestionMark(Rval, Gval, Bval, left)

        # Blue Line
        BlueLine(left)

        # Line to see if we are dropping frame
        DropFrameTest(left)
        pyglet.text.Label('Left', font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=34, x=(window.width*0.753), y= (window.height*0.05), anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center', color = (255, 0, 0, 150)).draw()
        ScreenSwap = 0

    else:     
        DrawQuestionMark(Rval, Gval, Bval, right)

        # Blue Line
        BlueLine(right)

        # Line to see if we are dropping frame
        DropFrameTest(right)
        pyglet.text.Label('Right', font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=34, x=(window.width*0.877), y= (window.height*0.05), anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center', color = (0, 255, 0, 150)).draw()
        ScreenSwap = 1

    fps = math.ceil(pyglet.clock.get_fps())
    labelStr = str(int(fps))+' Hz'
    pyglet.text.Label(labelStr, font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36, x=(window.width*0.02), y= (window.height*0.05), anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center', color = (250, 250, 250, 150)).draw()    

    if menu:
        for i in range(len(labelSysInfo)): # labelSysInfo is a list of 8 strings of text
            pyglet.text.Label(labelSysInfo[i], font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=18, x=(window.width*0.75) , y= (window.height*0.95)-(i*window.height*0.03), anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center', color = (210, 210, 255, 255)).draw()
```

Comment: You are creating new `Label` instances on every `on_draw` call. Have you tried keeping the label objects and updating/re-instantiating them only when the window dimensions [change](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/resizing_the_window.html)?

Comment: That did improve the frame rate! Thanks a lot. I'm still dropping frames but only once in a while, so i'll look into it. Could you answer the question so that I can vote for it?

Comment: for me, your gratitude is vote enough. By the way. Pyglet will curb the framerate whenever no or little changes occur to the active screen (I think). Your framerate dropping might just be a result of a nothing new happening once your menus are done.

Comment: That might actually explain a periodical fluctuation in the frame rate. I noticed that the frame rate is steady for about 85 seconds, and then goes down (about 116 Hz) for about 0.5 seconds, and then goes up to 120 Hz. I will need to find the source of the problem. Steady frame rate is critical for my application. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Katzwinkel, my code is now running at a decent frame rate. I simply kept the label objects and updated them only when there was a change.